# Next.js Rewrite: Modify response

Tags: next.js, url-rewriting

Using Next.js's [rewrite feature](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites) I would like to be able to intercept the response and change e.g. headers and even links in the body.

I have a front-facing next.js web app which is accessible by the visitors. Some parts come from a different service, but the visitor should not see those details, for her the URL should look like all comes from a single source, and all navigation goes inside the same hostname.
I used the `rewrites()` of `next.config.js` according to [Incremental adoption of Next.js](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites#incremental-adoption-of-nextjs) and this works for the most part. But the responses from the other background service sometimes contain wrong URLs / hostnames. Those I would like to replace to match the public facing hostname of the web site.

I couldn't find any pointers on the next.js documentatin as to how best approach this problem. Maybe someone has a solution to share or there exist some middleware already?

Comment: @juliomalves can you make that into an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrites are simply a way to map a request path to a different destination path. Rewrites don't allow you to modify the contents of the page you're rewriting to.

You'll have to modify the destination app yourself to reflect the changes you want.